# Passing a value into Ajax enable WCF web service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have created an Ajax enabled WCF web service that contains this simple method:

```
 [OperationContract]
    public string ParameterizedConnectionTest(string word)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered the word: {0}", word);

    }
```

I can invoke the Web service with this client side JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function btn_Connect_onclick() {

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/MySimpleService.svc/ParameterizedConnectionTest",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data:'{"word":"Wolverine"}',
        success: function(data) {

            alert(data.d);

        }

    });

}
```

So basically when I click the input button what I get is a message box with the result from the Web service plus the new word. "You entered the word: Wolverine"

I want to know how I could pass the input value like "Wolverine" from a text box instead of being hardcoded and then display that value in another textbox instead of a message box.

Right now I am using a simple .html page.

thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" one of the answers, and vote up any answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
function btn_Connect_onclick() {

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/MySimpleService.svc/ParameterizedConnectionTest",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data:'{"word":"' + $('#inputTextBox').val() + '"}',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#result').val(data.d);

        }

    });

}
```

And the markup:

```
<input type="text" id="inputTextBox"/>
<input type="text" id="result"/>
```

Comment: @Karim79, Thanks a lot. I could not ask for a better snippet so clear and simple. This little code does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is 'how can I get a value from an input box'. You can do that using jQuery selectors and the `.val()` method. Also I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the data part, it looks like an object but it's a string. You know, you can also pass an real object there.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MySimpleService.svc/ParameterizedConnectionTest',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        word: $('input[name=something]').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow this code is not working, the snippet from Karin works.

Comment: That might be because I changed the data attribute to a real object which you might have missed.